# create yesterday's date folder yyyy-mm-dd using .bat

Tags: date, batch-file

I am attempting to create a prior date folder using the below script, and the problem is that it skips the month. To illustrate my point it ends up with `2016-2-`. Thus, any relevant feedback on this would be appreciated.

Ps: Current date from my machine: `3/3/2016`

Best,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
set vbs=%temp%\vbs.vbs
> %vbs% echo WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,Date)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do (
set newfold=%%a
)
del %vbs%
for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=/ " %%1 in ("%newfold%") do (
set month=%%2&set date=%%3&set year=%%4
md !date!-!month!-!year!
echo New folder created = !date!-!month!-!year!      
)
```

**EDIT:** `VBScript` using the `Weekday()` function

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set vbs=%temp%\vbs.vbs
>%vbs% echo dateYesterday=DateAdd("d",-1,Date): 
wdayYesterday=Weekday(dateYesterday): 
If wdayYesterday=1 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-2,dateYesterday) 
Else If wdayYesterday=7 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,dateYesterday)
Else WScript.Echo dateYesterday
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do (
set newfold=%%a
)
echo dateYesterday = %newfold%  ^(assumption: month/day/year^)
del %vbs%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%1 in ("%newfold%") do (
set month=%%2
set day=%%1
set year=%%3
)
md %day%-%month%-%year%
echo New folder created = %day%-%month%-%year%  ^(day/month/year^)
```

Comment: Add `echo yesterday = %newfold%` immediately after the `set newfold=%%a` command to check what you parse by the 2nd `for /f` loop...

Comment: following the addition of `PAUSE` in the above code in addition to your suggestion, one could read from the console window `yesteday= New folder created = 2016-3-`.

Comment: Sorry, you need to place `echo yesterday = %newfold%` after the `)` and before the `del %vbs%` command line...

Comment: it's alright... and thx for the amendment. However, please note from the updated console window: `yesterday= 3/3/2016 New folder created = 2016-3-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused the tokens in the 2nd `for /f` loop: assuming your date format is *month/day/year*, you need to change the `set` command line. Here is the corrected code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set vbs=%temp%\vbs.vbs
> %vbs% echo WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,Date)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do (
    set newfold=%%a
)
echo Yesterday = %newfold%  ^(assumption: month/day/year^)
del %vbs%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%1 in ("%newfold%") do (
    set month=%%2
    set day=%%1
    set year=%%3
)
md %day%-%month%-%year%
echo New folder created = %day%-%month%-%year%  ^(day/month/year^)
```

Since the 2nd `for /f` loop iterates once only (like also the 1st one), I moved all commands but `set` outside, so there is no need for delayed expansion any more.

---

To cover also the **EDIT** of your question where you want the date of the previous business day (so Saturdays and Sundays do not count), you could just extend the temporary VBScript:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set vbs=%temp%\vbs.vbs
> %vbs% echo dateYesterday=DateAdd("d",-1,Date): wdayYesterday=Weekday(dateYesterday): If wdayYesterday=1 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-2,dateYesterday) Else If wdayYesterday=7 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,dateYesterday) Else WScript.Echo dateYesterday
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do (
    set newfold=%%a
)
echo Yesterday = %newfold%  ^(assumption: month/day/year^)
del %vbs%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%1 in ("%newfold%") do (
    set month=%%2
    set day=%%1
    set year=%%3
)
md %day%-%month%-%year%
echo New folder created = %day%-%month%-%year%  ^(day/month/year^)
```

This approach uses the `Weekday()` function (in the `*.vbs` script) to get the current day of week (`1` is Sunday, `2` is Monday,..., `7` is Saturday).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful feedback. However, while executing the `.batch` on Mondays is there a way to make yesterday's folder reflect Friday's date and not Sunday (which is not a business day)?

Comment: Yes, but I would do that calculation in the VBScript using the `Weekday()` function; so you could replace the `WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,Date)` portion by: `dateYesterday=DateAdd("d",-1,Date): wdayYesterday=Weekday(dateYesterday): If wdayYesterday=1 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-2,dateYesterday) Else If wdayYesterday=7 Then WScript.Echo DateAdd("d",-1,dateYesterday) Else WScript.Echo dateYesterday`

Comment: Following your suggesition, please see above the edited script, which does not produce the expected outcome. Let me know in case I' ve missed something from your previous statement... Thx.

Comment: It was meant to be all in a single line, the `:` separates multiple commands; I will include my above comment in my answer; nevertheless, in future please do not change or extend the scope of an existing question; rather consider to post a new one...

Comment: Thanks for your advice as well as comments. Best,